# Searching in binary file C++

Tags: c++, file, class, c++11, file-io

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Student{
private:
    char name[40];
    char grade;
    float marks;
public:
    void getdata();
    void display();
    char* getname(){return name;}
    void search(fstream,char*);
};

void Student::getdata(){
    char ch;
    cin.get(ch);
    cout<<"Enter name : ";
    cin.getline(name,40);
    cout<<"Enter grade : ";
    cin>>grade;
    cout<<"Enter marks : ";
    cin>>marks;
    cout<<"\n";
}

void Student::display(){
    cout<<"Name : "<<name<<"\t";
    cout<<"Grade : "<<grade<<"\t";
    cout<<"Marks : "<<marks<<"\t"<<"\n";
}

void search(fstream fin,char* nm)/*initializing argument 1 of 'void search(std::fstream, char*)'*/{
    Student s;
    fin.open("stu.txt",ios::in|ios::binary);
    while(!fin){
        fin.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
        if(s.getname()==nm){
            cout<<"Record found !";
            s.display();
            break;
        }
    }
    fin.close();
}

int main(){
    system("cls");
    char nam[40];
    Student arts[3];
    fstream f;
    f.open("stu.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    if(!f){
        cerr<<"Cannot open file !";
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        arts[i].getdata();
        f.write((char*)&arts[i],sizeof(arts[i]));
    }
    f.close();
    cout<<"Enter name to be searched for : ";
    cin.getline(nam,40);
    char* p = new char[40];
    p=nam;
    search(f,p);/*synthesized method 'std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)' first required here*/
    getch();
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The above program first creates a file "stu.txt" and writes user-given input to the file.
It is then supposed to search for a record based on the name the user enters ( using the search() function ). I'm getting errors when calling search() and also defining search(). I've put in the errors the compiler throws as comment lines. Could anyone explain what's going wrong in there ?

Comment: You cannot have a `fstream` parameter because `fstream` cannot be copied. Use `fstream&` instead.

Comment: Thanks ! That removed the errors !

Comment: Could you explain why fstream& works ?

Comment: It passes the stream by reference (look up pass by reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fstream` is not copyable, so you have to pass `fstream` as a reference, or in c++11, move it.

Given you access `f` after calling `search`, it is best to pass it by reference.

Change your function to accept the `fstream` as a **reference**:

```
void search(fstream& fin,char* nm)
```